# How to save uploaded file data into text file locally ? webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I have a file upload control and once i browse a file (may be image/text) and click on save means the file should be saved to some folder in my Local Computer .

**I am trying like :**

```
self.save =function(){

var formdata = new FormData(); //FormData object

var opmlFile = $('#FFtoSP')[0]; // i get my entire uploaded file details 
formdata.append("opmlFile", opmlFile.files[0]); // i am appending to formdata

 // Now my formdata holds the data and now how come i save it in text file in my local machine dynamiclly 

};
```

**My view :**

```
<form>
 <input name="file" type="file" id="FFtoSP"  />
 <input type="button" id=""  value="save" data-bind="click:$data.save" /> 
</form>
```

**My controller code :**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(string id)
{

    string uploadedPath = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++) // i get count zero for IE and one for other browsers
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i]; //Uploaded file

        //Use the following properties to get file's name, size and MIMEType
        int fileSize = file.ContentLength;
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        fileName = "Contract" + "_" + "CreateContract" + "_" + fileName;
        string mimeType = file.ContentType;
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Upload"), fileName);//path where i want to save


        //To save file, use SaveAs method
        file.SaveAs(path); //File will be saved in application root 


    }
    return Json(uploadedPath);

}
```

Any clues can be of great Help

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/01/file-upload-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx

Comment: @KiranChalla thats a nice link . i sorted my issue in a other way but there is some compatibility issues i am using `formdata`in my script file . so when ever i use it, in IE 8+ the uploaded file data `Request.Files.Count` getting zero but where as other in browsers i am getting count and everything fine . added my controller code . any insight is helpful mate